# how to make css sub menu links longer than parent link

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS vertical menu with horizontal sub menu links

http://jsfiddle.net/xmgMq/1/

i am trying to make the sub menu links the same width as the text of the link without changing the width of the parent link.

here is my CSS:

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 400px; /******* MODIFIED ********/
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;stac
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

i have made the width of the sub menu links 200px which then doesnt display all the text if its longer or if i make it 100% it only does 100% of the parent link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the li's to take the width of the widest li - use `css tables`

```
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
}
.sub-menu li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/xmgMq/8/)**

Comment: can it make all the sub menu links the same width?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for

```
.vertical-nav li uL li{width:auto !important;min-width:51%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

make li

```
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
```